# Xamarin.Forms Font is obsolete

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

When I am trying to create anew label on **Xamarin.Forms**, I get the following Warning:

```
about = new Label { Text = "" ,      
                TextColor=Color.Black,
                Font = Font.SystemFontOfSize(16),//Warning occurred here 
                XAlign = TextAlignment.End,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand};
```

> 'Xamarin.Forms.Label.Font' is obsolete: 'Please use the Font
>   attributes which are on the class itself. Obsoleted in v1.3.0'

What this warning means and what I should do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just listen to the warning and change it to `FontSize`. 
In next releases of `Xamarin.Forms` this property can be removed and your code no longer will compile.

Marking some method/property as obsolete is very often used by maintainers of libraries to warn users that this particular member can be removed in next releases of library.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `FontSize`, `FontFamily`, and `FontAttributes` properties of the `Label` class instead.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts/

Comment: thanks ..i accept another question because the different is seconds on post answer :)